# swift pass json decode type to http request

Tags: json, swift

I want to make a static func that could return a stuct defined like this:

```
struct Category: Codable {
    public let data: Array<CateItem>
    public let status: Int
    public let msg: String
}
```

And I have write a static func like this:

```
static func Get(codePoint: String, responseType: Codable){
    let urlString = UrlUtils.GetUrl(codePoint: codePoint)
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){
        (data,response,error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error!)
        }else{
            if let data = data{
                JSONDecoder().decode(responseType, from: data)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

and invoke the method like this:

```
HttpRequests.Get(codePoint: "getCategoryList", responseType:  Category)
```

but here `responseType` will not work.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass type of struct, not protocol.

First, make generic constraint for your method which says that `T` has to conform to `Decodable` (since you need it just for decoding, you don’t need conforming to `Encodable`)

Then say that parameter should be of type `T.Type` - this allows compiler to **infer** type of `T`, you can avoid using this parameter, see at the end of the answer

```
static func Get<T: Decodable>(codePoint: String, responseType: T.Type) { ... }
```

... so `T` will be type which you'll pass to method.

---

Then for `JSONDecoder`'s `decode` method use type of `T`

```
JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
```

and then when you want to call your method, pass type of your struct like you did it within decoding

```
HttpRequests.Get(codePoint: "getCategoryList", responseType: Category.self)
```

---

Also note that your call is async so for returning data you'll need **completion handler** defined as parameter of your method

```
completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void
```

---

*note that names of methods should start with small capital letters*

```
static func get<T: Decodable>(codePoint: String, responseType: T.Type, completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {

    let urlString = UrlUtils.GetUrl(codePoint: codePoint)
    let url = URL(string: urlString)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in

        guard let data = data else {
            print(error!)
            return completion(nil)
        }

        do {
            let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(decoded)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

---

```
HttpRequests.get(codePoint: "getCategoryList", responseType: Category.self) { response in
    if let category = response {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

You can also avoid using `responseType` parameter since type of `T` can be inferred from the type of parameter of completion closure

```
static func get<T: Codable>(codePoint: String, completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void) { ... }
```

---

```
HttpRequests.get(codePoint: "getCategoryList") { (category: Category?) -> Void in ... }
```

Comment: By the way, the `responseType` parameter is not really necessary because it can be inferred from the closure type. Although there are rare situations when you want the types to be different.